# range along row or column of tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, how can I calculate the the range along rows or columns of a tensor?
Where range is max - min.

In Matlab this can be done with 'range'

```
a=[ 1 2 3; 4 5 6]
range(a) = [3 3 3] %this is the range along columns of a
range(a') = [2 2]  %range along rows of a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following,

Assuming (`range = max - min`)

```
# Axis 0
res_1 = tf.reduce_max(a, axis=0) - tf.reduce_min(a, axis=0)
# Axis 1
res_2 = tf.reduce_max(a, axis=1) - tf.reduce_min(a, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.get_shape()` to get the dimensions of a `tensor` which you can further use in `range` function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
print(c.get_shape())
>>> TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])

print(c.get_shape()[0].value)
>>> 2
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified range = max-min